# Generate plotly DataTable from SQL query

Tags: python, sql, datatable, plotly-dash

I'm quite a new to dash and python, I am currently trying to have a `callback` for `datatable` which retrieves from the `SQL` on my computer.
However, I am not able to do so.

Any idea why? I got this error:

```
columns = [{'num': i, 'id': i} for i in data.columns],data=[]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined
```

Here what I have implemented so far;

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_table
from dash.dependencies import Output, Input
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from random import random
import plotly
import pyodbc
global data
def connectSQLServer(driver, server, db):
    connSQLServer = pyodbc.connect(
        r'DRIVER={' + driver + '};'
        r'SERVER=' + server + ';'
        r'DATABASE=' + db + ';'
        r'Trusted_Connection=yes;',
        autocommit=True
    )
    return connSQLServer


app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([dash_table.DataTable(id='raw_data',

                                            columns = [{'num': i, 'id': i} for i in data.columns],data=[]
                                            #data = data.to_dict('records')
                                            ),
                       dcc.Interval(id='interval_component',
                                    interval=1000,
                                    n_intervals=0
                                    )
                       ])


@app.callback(Output('raw_data', 'data'), [Input('interval_component', 'n_intervals')])
def update_table(n_intervals):

    dataSQL = []  # set an empty list
    global data
    sql_conn = connectSQLServer(
        'ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server', 'DESKTOP\SQL', 'display')
    cursor = sql_conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SELECT num,ID FROM dbo.stats")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        dataSQL.append(list(row))
        labels = ['num', 'id']
        data = pd.DataFrame.from_records(dataSQL, columns=labels)
        data = data.to_dict('records')
        return {'data': [data]}


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've set up the `Output` to pass to the `data` prop, so your return value should simply be the `data` variable, like this:

`return data`

By putting it into a dictionary, Dash is looking for a data prop of the data prop, which does not exist, and that's why you get the error that data is not defined.

Comment: Hi, i have tried but still error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 26, in <module>
    columns = [{'num': i, 'id': i} for i in data.columns],data=[]
NameError: name 'data' is not defined

Comment: You don't have `data` defined outside that callback yet, so initialize your table with `columns=[],data=[]` and then set up the `columns` value in your callback and use a multi-output to pass back the `data` and the `columns` values.

Comment: i tried and now i have a `callback error updating raw_data` as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60664563/update-dash-datatable-every-few-seconds-with-new-rows-from-sql

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DataFrame, it's easy with dash.

Use sqllachemy or something like that, define the engine

- Your query

  `query = f'''SELECT num,ID FROM dbo.stats'''`
- Get data from db and create a dataframe

  `df = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_sql_query(query, engine, coerce_float=False))`

  and then you populate the datatable:

  ```
  # return the dataframe and populate datatable
  Dash_table.DataTable(
      columns=[{"name": i, "id": i, "hideable": True} for i in df.columns],
      data=df.to_dict('records'),
  ```

....

Regards,